# How do I iterate through a dict while also removing newline characters?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate through a dictionary and remove newline characters, and having difficult with parsing the items.

Say we have

```
line_contents = {"user_id": "6GrH6gp09pqYykGv86D6Dg", "text": "Decent selection of more than just bar food. \n\nJumbo fish sandwich is aptly named. \n\nSeem to be generous with the pour.", "business_id": "fNGIbpazjTRdXgwRY_NIXA", "likes": 0, "date": "2013-04-22", "type": "tip"}

#I've tried:
line_contents=dict(map(strip(),x) for x in line_contents.items())
#but ^ doesn't work. I can't figure out how the map function or the dictionary comprehension works

#I eventually want:
line_contents = {"user_id": "6GrH6gp09pqYykGv86D6Dg", "text": "Decent selection of more than just bar food. Jumbo fish sandwich is aptly named. Seem to be generous with the pour.", "business_id": "fNGIbpazjTRdXgwRY_NIXA", "likes": 0, "date": "2013-04-22", "type": "tip"}
```

I'm tempted to iterate through the dictionary elements with a typical `for` loop but would like to try dict comprehension as I never have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you aren't using a dictionary comprehension.  That is a function call with a single argument: a generator expression.  A dictionary comprehension would be more like this:

```
line_contents = {key: value.replace("\n", "") for key, value in line_contents.items()}
```

**Edit**: niemmi made a good point that the values are not all strings.  Therefore, you should use something similar to his suggestion:

```
line_contents = {k: v.replace("\n", "") if isinstance(v, basestring) else v for k,v in line_contents.items()}
```

I used `basestring` instead of niemmi's `str` because they are actually unicode.  In Python 3, you should use `str`.

What was wrong with yours? Well, you are giving `dict` one argument.  Consider this:

```
argument = []
for x in line_contents.items():
    argument.append(map(strip(), x))

line_contents = dict(argument)
```

That is pretty much what you are doing.  For each key-value pair, you are giving `map()` two arguments `strip()` and `x`.  For one call of `map(strip(), x)`, you are in effect doing this:

```
function = strip()
result = []
for item in x:
    result.append(function(item))
```

Now you must see the problem.  For one thing, `strip` is not defined.  For another thing, you are supposed to supply `map` with a function, not what the function returns.  If you wanted to use `str.strip`, do it like this:

```
map(str.strip, x)
```

The problem with that is that `str.strip()` strips from the ends; it does not remove the new lines that appear in the middle.

Comment: Weird, that doesn't seem to work. When I insert a print line of `print line_contents` on the dictionary line right before the dictionary comprehension line, it's showing what I believe are raw strings: `{u'user_id': u'6GrH6gp09pqYykGv86D6Dg', u'text': u'Decent selection of more than just bar food. \n\nJumbo fish sandwich is aptly named. \n\nSeem to be generous with the pour.', u'business_id': u'fNGIbpazjTRdXgwRY_NIXA', u'likes': 0, u'date': u'2013-04-22', u'type': u'tip'}` Should this have any effect on what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Does it have an error?  Does it change some things but not all?  The `u` means unicode, not raw.  If they were raw strings, that would make a difference, but actually, a raw string is nothing different from a normal string.  "Raw" refers to how it is created, not what it becomes.

Comment: No error, the `\n` still appears in the dictionary when I print it again.

Comment: @simplycoding: I copied code without checking it first ;)  Niemmi's suggestion doesn't work with unicode strings.  See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dict comprehension but since some of your values are not strings you have to take that into account:

```
line_contents = {k: v.replace('\n', '') if isinstance(v, str) else v for k, v in line_contents.items()}
```

In case both keys and values contain newline you can use `dict` builtin:

```
line_contents = dict([y.replace('\n', '') if isinstance(y, str) else y for y in x] 
                     for x in line_contents.items())
```

Of course dict comprehension would still work but it would look quite messy:

```
line_contents = {k: v for k, v in
                 ([y.replace('\n', '') if isinstance(y, str) else y for y in x]
                  for x in line_contents.items())
                 }
```

Comment: Turns out the dictionary `line_contents` is in Unicode. So it comes in as `line_contents = {u'user_id': u'6GrH6gp09pqYykGv86D6Dg', u'text': u'Decent selection of more than just bar food. \n\nJumbo fish sandwich is aptly named. \n\nSeem to be generous with the pour.', u'business_id': u'fNGIbpazjTRdXgwRY_NIXA', u'likes': 0, u'date': u'2013-04-22', u'type': u'tip'}`. Your suggestion obviously worked if it wasn't Unicode. Any idea how to go about this?